# Can I change the order of rows without specifying a column as the clustering key?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I know I can change the on-disk sorting to descending by defining a table like this:

```sql
create table timeseries (
  event_type text,
  insertion_time timestamp,
  event blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC);
```

But the problem is that now `insertion_time` is part of a composite unique constraint (`event_type` + `insertation_time`) which is not desired.

Is there any way to change the order without making the column a primary key? Something like this:

```sql
create table timeseries (
  event_type text,
  insertion_time timestamp,
  event blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_type)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible because in the second table schema, there will only every be one row for every single partition. Another way of putting it is -- there are no rows to sort since there is only ever one row.

You can only specify the `CLUSTERING ORDER` if there is a clustering column to sort. Cheers!

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: No. Like I said, there is nothing to sort if the partition only contains one row. Cheers!